# Grey screen in release mode (IOS - Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, release, testflight

I am getting a grey screen on two pages in my app, I m facing this problem only in release mode when I installed it from TestFlight. there is no error in debug mode, and it works fine also when I run it in release mode from android studio.

this is my code on two screens:

First screen:

```
 ViewModelBuilder<TraineeCoachViewModel>.nonReactive(
  builder: (context, model, child) => Layout(
    title: coachFullName,
    body:
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(Assets.rightBackground),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
        ),
      ),
      child:
       SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: model.getCoachModel,
              initialData: null,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<CoachModel?> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
                  return const Loading();
                }

                final CoachModel coachmodel = snapshot.data!;

                final List<String> additionalPhotos = coachmodel.album ?? [];

                final String profilePhoto = coachmodel.profilePhoto ?? "";

                final List<String?> imagesToSlide = [
                  profilePhoto,
                  ...additionalPhotos
                ];

                final _slideImageItemwidth =
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
                final _slideImageItemHeight =
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5;

                return
                 SingleChildScrollView(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                 child:
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Container(
                            height: _slideImageItemwidth,
                            width: _slideImageItemHeight,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                              width: 1.0,
                            )),
                            child: PageView.builder(
                                itemCount: imagesToSlide.length,
                                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                  final String? image = imagesToSlide[index];
                                  return Hero(
                                      tag: index.toString() + "S",
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                fullscreenDialog: true,
                                                builder: (BuildContext
                                                        context) =>
                                                    HeroPhoto(
                                                        imageUrl: image,
                                                        tag:
                                                            index.toString() +
                                                                "S"))),
                                        child: CardItemProfilePhoto(
                                          iconSize: 50,
                                          imageUrl: image,
                                          withBorderDecoration: false,
                                          size: Size(_slideImageItemwidth,
                                              _slideImageItemwidth),
                                        ),
                                      ));
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        verticalSpaceMedium,
                        additionalPhotos.isNotEmpty
                            ? GridView.builder(
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: additionalPhotos.length,
                                gridDelegate:
                                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                        crossAxisCount: 4,
                                        childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                                        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0),
                                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                  return Hero(
                                    tag: "${index + 1}",
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            fullscreenDialog: true,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                HeroPhoto(
                                                    imageUrl:
                                                        additionalPhotos[
                                                            index],
                                                    tag: "${index + 1}"),
                                          )),
                                      child: LayoutBuilder(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            BoxConstraints constraints) {
                                          return CardItemProfilePhoto(
                                            iconSize: 20,
                                            imageUrl: additionalPhotos[index],
                                            size: constraints.biggest,
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                })
                            : Container(),
                        coachmodel.bio != null
                            ? verticalSpaceMediumS
                            : Container(),
                        coachmodel.bio != null
                            ? AppText.headingTwo(
                                localizations.bio + ":",
                              )
                            : Container(),
                        verticalSpaceNormal,
                        Text(
                          coachmodel.bio ?? "",
                          style: captionStyle,
                        ),
                        coachmodel.bio != null
                            ? verticalSpaceMediumS
                            : Container(),
                        StreamBuilder(
                          stream: model.coursesStream,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<List<CourseModel>> snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
                              return const Loading(
                                showBackgroundColor: false,
                              );
                            }

                            final courses = snapshot.data
                                ?.where((element) =>
                                    element.isSameType(courseType))
                                .toList();

                           
                            if (model.isBusy) {
                              WidgetsBinding.instance!
                                  .addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                                model.setBusy(false);
                              });
                            }

                            return ListView.builder(
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: courses!.length,
                                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                  final courseModel = courses[index];

                                  bool found = false;
                                  if (courses[index].traineesIn != null &&
                                      model.userId != '') {
                                    found = courses[index]
                                        .traineesIn!
                                        .contains(model.userId);
                                  }

                                  ///Subscription button
                                  return SizedBox(
                                      height: screenHeightPercentage(context,
                                          percentage: 0.10),
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      child: SubscriptionItemShaped(
                                          params: getParams(courseModel,
                                              model, localizations,
                                              traineeIdFound: found,
                                              context: context)));
                                });
                          },
                        ),
                      ]),
               );
             },
           ),
         ],
     ),
       ),
    ),
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  ),
  viewModelBuilder: () => getIt<TraineeCoachViewModel>()
    ..coachId = coachID
    ..coachName = coachFullName
    ..init(),
);
```

Second screen:

```
ViewModelBuilder<NotificationsViewModel>.nonReactive(
  builder: (context, model, child) {
    return Layout(
      title: localizations.subs_detail,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(Assets.rightBackground),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: screenHeightPercentage(context, percentage: 0.03)),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder<TraineeModel?>(
                    future: model.getTraineeModel(subsModel.traineeId!),
                    initialData: null,
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<TraineeModel?> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
                        return const Loading();
                      }

                      final TraineeModel userModel = snapshot.data!;

                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: screenWidthPercentage(context,
                                percentage: 0.05)),
                        child: Column(
                        
                          children: [
                            Text(localizations.trainee_detail.toUpperCase(),
                                style:
                                    heading1Style.copyWith(fontSize: 20)),
                            verticalSpaceMedium,
                            CircularProfilePhoto(
                              imageurl: userModel.profilePhoto,
                              iconSize: 30,
                              height: screenHeightPercentage(context,
                                  percentage: 0.17),
                              width: screenHeightPercentage(context,
                                  percentage: 0.17),
                            ),
                            verticalSpaceMedium,
                            Padding(
                              padding: langauge.appLocal.languageCode ==
                                      'ar'
                                  ? EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: screenWidthPercentage(context,
                                          percentage: 0.20),
                                      right: screenWidthPercentage(context,
                                          percentage: 0.2),
                                    )
                                  : EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: screenWidthPercentage(context,
                                          percentage: 0.23),
                                    ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        userModel.fullName!.toUpperCase(),
                                        style: heading1Style.copyWith(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: kcWhiteColor),
                                      ),
                                      verticalSpaceMedium,
                                      Text(
                                        userModel.gender.toUpperCase(),
                                        style: heading1Style.copyWith(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: kcWhiteColor),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      userModel.height != null
                                          ? verticalSpaceMedium
                                          : Container(),
                                      //  userModel.height != null ?
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: screenWidthPercentage(
                                                context,
                                                percentage: 0.25)),
                                        child: Text(
                                          userModel.height != null
                                              ? '${userModel.height!.toString()} ${localizations.cm}'
                                              : '0.0  ${localizations.cm}',
                                          style: heading1Style.copyWith(
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: kcWhiteColor),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      //: Container(),
                                      verticalSpaceMedium,
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: screenWidthPercentage(
                                                context,
                                                percentage: 0.25)),
                                        child: Text(
                                          userModel.weight != null
                                              ? '${userModel.weight!.toString()} ${localizations.kg}'
                                              : '0.0  ${localizations.kg}',
                                          style: heading1Style.copyWith(
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              color: kcWhiteColor),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                verticalSpaceMedium,
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: kcWhiteColor,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                ),
                verticalSpaceMedium,

                Text(localizations.course_detail.toUpperCase(),
                    style: heading1Style.copyWith(fontSize: 20)),
                verticalSpaceMedium,
                Text(subsModel.courseName!.toUpperCase(),
                    style: heading1Style.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 25, color: kcWhiteColor)),
                verticalSpaceMedium,

                Text(
                    '${subsModel.coursePrice} ${localizations.currency_code}',
                    style: heading1Style.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 25, color: kcWhiteColor)),

                StreamBuilder<SubscriptionModel>(
                    stream: model.getSubscription(subsModel.id!),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Loading(
                          showBackgroundColor: false,
                        );
                      }

                      return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: screenHeightPercentage(context,
                                  percentage: 0.1)),
                          child: snapshot.data!.subscriptionStatus.value ==
                                      SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS
                                          .WAITING_PAYMENT.value ||
                                  snapshot.data!.subscriptionStatus.value ==
                                      SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS.REJECTED.value ||
                                  snapshot.data!.subscriptionStatus.value ==
                                      SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS.BLOCKED.value
                              ? StatusText(
                                  status: snapshot
                                      .data!.subscriptionStatus.value,
                                  subscriptionModel: snapshot.data!,
                                  localizations: localizations,
                                  notificationsViewModel: model,
                                )
                              : Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ButtonWidget(
                                        subscriptionModel: snapshot.data!,
                                        localizations: localizations,
                                        notificationsViewModel: model,
                                        text: localizations.accept
                                            .toUpperCase(),
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          model.accept(snapshot.data!);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    //  ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ButtonWidget(
                                        subscriptionModel: snapshot.data!,
                                        localizations: localizations,
                                        notificationsViewModel: model,
                                        text: localizations.chat_status
                                            .toUpperCase(),
                                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          model.chat(snapshot.data!);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ButtonWidget(
                                        subscriptionModel: snapshot.data!,
                                        localizations: localizations,
                                        notificationsViewModel: model,
                                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          model.reject(
                                              snapshot.data!, context);
                                        },
                                        text: localizations.reject
                                            .toUpperCase(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ButtonWidget(
                                        subscriptionModel: snapshot.data!,
                                        localizations: localizations,
                                        notificationsViewModel: model,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          model.block(
                                              snapshot.data!, context);
                                        },
                                        text: localizations.block
                                            .toUpperCase(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ));
                    })
              ],
            ),


          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  viewModelBuilder: () => getIt<NotificationsViewModel>()..init(),
);
```

I have been testing it on various devices, and I got the same problem.

Comment: Run it in debug mode and you will probably see that one of the widgets isn't properly built. It's hard to say where the error is but usually when you nest a column inside a row flutter complains.

Comment: there is no problem in debug mode, no error shows in the log.

Comment: Amina, I wonder anybody is going to answer your question. Such an amount of code and non resolvable dependencies. Strip down your code step by step and see, at which point is is showing more than grey.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, I have two copies of the project, so the android studio has the new copy and Xcode has the old one.  that means I uploaded the old code to TestFlight hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Amina Bekir, the issue was that they had two copies of the project, so Android Studio had the new copy while Xcode has the old one.

Then the old code was uploaded to TestFlight making this behavior to appear.